# CORS error when calling SF rest api from localhost

Tags: cors

I have a small JS application running on localhost. I am getting an access token through the user-agent flow (this works fine).

I then make an http request to the identity endpoint to get back my user info and this throws a CORS error.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://test.salesforce.com/services/data/v48.0' from origin 'https://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have added `localhost:3000` under the CORS whitelist in Salesforce but this doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

The [Identity URL](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_using_openid.htm&type=5) returned as part of an oauth response is not one of the endpoints that supports CORS whitelisting.

> The Identity URL is returned in the id scope parameter. For example,
> https://login.salesforce.com/id/00Dx0000000BV7z/005x00000012Q9P.

Only the following APIs are supported per [CORS whitelisting documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=extend_code_cors.htm&type=5).

- Analytics REST API
- Bulk API
- Connect REST API
- Salesforce IoT REST API
- Lightning Out
- REST API
- User Interface API
- Apex REST